# how to read a specific column from existing SQLiteBatabase in Android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a database having 28 rows just for saving app data. My goal is to read One specific column (not one value) from it.

However, I don't want to read all columns at once, because it's slow as I have blob's in db too. Instead, I'd like to read just one column at a time, separately. Can you plese help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read one ROW do something along those lines:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id='5' LIMIT 1;
```

where 'id' is supposer do be in the table 'tablename'
or else try something like this:

```
SELECT datafield FROM tablename WHERE 1;
```

which will give you all the 'datafield' data from the table (ie. a Column).

If this doesn't help you at all then post the code you are already using.

Comment: ThankYou for your response. Can you please post an example program using this statement--SELECT datafield FROM tablename WHERE 1; which is used to retrieve specific columns from existing database.

Comment: Show me how you are doing it now and I'll try to change your code.